# How can I connect my Korg 01/W directly to my Dell laptop

Tags: midi, korg

I have a Korg 01/W, connected to a Roland Sound Canvas, connected to an Presonus Audiobox interface, connected by USB cable to my Dell laptop. I have the Light version of Cubase. The manual shows the connections using an external sound module(i.e. like my Roland) but I would rather use the Korg directly.

I tried bypassing the Roland but could not get any sound. I can get sound using the aforementioned hook up, but I'm getting sounds from both the Korg & the Sound Canvas & also latency issues which sound like what is coming from the Roland. Any suggestions?

Comment: What is your Korg generating? If it is purely midi data then where would you get sounds from?

Answer (score 1):

According to [this page](http://www.vintagesynth.com/korg/01w.php) the Korg only has midi output as opposed to newer devices, which also offer USB directly. So you definitely **need** some MIDI to USB interface, but trying a different one is always a good idea. (Presonus is not relevant for the question, since it is only handling analogue signals.)

Answer (score 0):

Yamaha MD-BT01 is a wireless Bluetooth MIDI solution that you can use. 
If your PC is too old to support Bluetooth LE, then you will also need WIDI Bud.